# How to prove $\cos{\frac{\pi}{11}}$ is a root of

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I want to show that $x=\cos{\frac{\pi}{11}}$ is a solution of equation :
$$8x^2-4x+\frac{1}{x}-4=4\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{2}}$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: Rearrange and square the equation to get a fifth-degree equation, then recognize it as a Chebyskev Polynomial.

Answer (score 4):

We have to prove that for $x=\cos\frac{\pi}{11}$ we have:

$$ 4x(2x^2-1)-(4x^2-1)=4x\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{2}}\tag{1}$$
or:
$$ 4\cos\frac{\pi}{11}\cos\frac{2\pi}{11}-\frac{\sin\frac{3\pi}{11}}{\sin\frac{\pi}{11}}=4\cos\frac{\pi}{11}\sin\frac{\pi}{22}\tag{2}$$
that is equivalent to:
$$ \sin\frac{4\pi}{11}-\sin\frac{3\pi}{11}=2\sin\frac{2\pi}{11}\sin\frac{\pi}{22}\tag{3}$$
or to:
$$ 2\cos\frac{7\pi}{22}\sin\frac{\pi}{22}=2\sin\frac{2\pi}{11}\sin\frac{\pi}{22}\tag{4}$$
that is trivial since $\cos\frac{7\pi}{22}=\sin\frac{4\pi}{22}=\sin\frac{2\pi}{11}.$